# Any good module/quest for 6 Lvl 3 PCs?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, published-adventures

I'm a new-ish DM and me and my friends have beeen playing 3.5 for fun the past few weeks. 
 (They all created character and I just threw monsters at them in arena style combat) Now they want to start actual quests, and the veterans of the group want to go by the books to make things run a bit smoother. I've looked around online for .pdf's but nothing really caught my eye. Does any body have any suggestion? I leveled up the group together so they are all Lvl 3, and consist of an Elf Ranger (Has been 1-hitting recently like crazy. New Player), Human Fighter (Tank, Semi-Veteran), Halfing Rogue (Dual Wield Shortswords, Veteran), Elf Cleric (N00B, but fun to mess with. Healer), Human Monk (Always Stoned, Played by AMAZING Vet, so funny), and a Gnomish Wizard (Illusionist, New Player).

Comment: There's a lot. If you want us to actually provide any decent recommendations, you're going to have to provide us with some kind of criteria for what you want to do in that adventure.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### Premise

Unfortunately, despite most of the official adventure books being written for "4 to 6 players", 6 characters is not really a thing that works unless you do some serious hack to every encounter.
& characters win more easily (because there's more damage in the pot and because in a 6vs4 everybody hitting the same target presses the advantage even more) and the reduced experience they get when you divide the loot by 6 won't stop them from leveling at the same ratio a group of 4 players would (lower level characters get xp faster), which means they still get an easier life.

I've played Return to the Temple of Elemental Evil (which has a fanmade online 3.5e conversion) with 6 players (it's an adventure module starting at level 4) and my impression is that, while you can get the plot from the premade adventure, you need to pump up the encounters, which leads to my second point.

### On premade plots

They are premade and as the saying tells us, *no plan survives contact with the players".
Once you're doing all the encounters again anyway, the value of a premade is highly devalued (and even with 4 players, if the characters are even slightly optimizing - and the game punishes with death those characters who aren't - the pre-written encounters are usually far from challenging).

So, if you really want a premade, once you don't expect to find a really good one I'd suggest Forge of Fury, which is level 3-6 IIRC (be aware it's 3e so some conversion is needed, which is not a problem since you're remaking statblocks anyway)

Comment: Cool thanks. I Have no problem beefing up monsters and npcs, as it is they will sometimes barely walk out of one of my encounters alive (more because they're a little dumb, kick in the door type players) I was actually just looking at the Shackled City, might actually do that... any pros/cons for anyone who's used it?

Comment: @user14963 IIRC, The Forge of Fury is pretty heavy on the figurative doors to kick. I've also heard good things about the Shackled City and surely some part of Expedition to Unedrmountain are suitable to your needs, but I didn't want my answer to be a list.

Comment: I'm currently playing in the Shackled city Campaign and as far as the player side goes, it's a lot of fun. Though we had some problems with xp/loot ratio mostly playing it with 3 players (too much xp too little loot :p). The encounters were a bit on the easy side, but we are at least slightly optimized